# Emacs cperl indentation of __DATA__ block

Tags: perl, emacs, indentation

Using Emacs 26.1 with cperl, it indents **DATA** like so:

```
__DATA__
abcdef
    ghijkl
```

Haven't found a fix for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like `cperl-mode` does not recognize the `__DATA__` block. Instead it believes that `abcdef` is a regular Perl statement, and then sees that there is no semicolon at the end of that line, and therefore it assumes the statement continues on the next line and uses [`cperl-continued-statement-offset`](https://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode/blob/master/cperl-mode.el#L282) to indent the line with `ghijkl`. Try put a semicolon at the end of the previous line, to verify this

Comment: Yes Håkon, it seems you are correct. With a semicolon at the end of the first line, the second line does not become intented.

Comment: Probably won't make a difference, but have you tried using `__END__` instead of `__DATA__`. In a script, these are the same. (In a module, these are different.)

Comment: Yes @ikegami, the same thing happens with an `__END__` block.

Comment: Please clarify the problem: what kind of indentation would you like to see instead (also make it precise whether you're talking about the case of hitting TAB to reindent a line or reindenting a whole region (or yet something else), since these can be handled differently).

Comment: @Stefan: Hitting CR in a `__DATA__` block indents the next line; I want no automatic indentation there. Also, the `__DATA__` block gets reindented whenever I write some code above it. For example, opening a block will shift all code below it to the right, until the block is closed; this is of course expected behavior. But the `__DATA__` block ends up as above, although it wasn't indented to begin with. I would prefer that the indenter don't touch the `__DATA__` block at all.

Comment: @Stefan I assume you are very familiar with Emacs (given your profile), but probably not so much with Perl. Let me clarify, since you seem like you could have some solution to offer: everything that comes after the line `__DATA__` in Perl isn't code but rather plain text, and should therefore not be automatically indented (and indenting the whole document should not modify formatting there).